# Getting timezone value in mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone

How can i get current timezone in mysql .

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql

Answer (score 0):

May be i'm don't undestand question but...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 0):

It's the first (and only) column of the first (and only) row of the result of this SELECT query:

SELECT @@global.time_zone;

If you want the session time zone you can use:

SELECT @@session.time_zone;

The result is like this:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| Europe/Paris       |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```