# MySql unix_time() function with only date argument

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

Ok, so the following works fine

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
```

But if I give only a date argument, like in:

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30');
```

Then somehow I am getting the timestamp equivalent to 2007-11-30 18:30 GMT. Can I somehow reset it to give timestamp for the beginning of that particular day? Like  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30'); should give the timestamp equivalent of UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 00:00:00'); I need to filter out some records from a table based an event that happend after a certain date.
Thanks

[EDIT]: I don't know how but this seems to be working as expected now. Screenshots:  [2007-11:30 00:00:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXUHH.jpg) [2007-11:30 18:30:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUEWx.jpg) [2007-11:30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joC17.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it But i am getting same timestamp for '2007-11-30 00:00:00' and '2007-11-30'

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 00:00:00');
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 00:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                            1196361000 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30');
+------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30') |
+------------------------------+
|                   1196361000 |
+------------------------------+
```

Can you run these queries on your machine and check timestamp values.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. I think this is related to the timezone of our system. Can you check the timezone of your msyql and add to the answer. Thanks. Help: [how to find the timezone of mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I also checked, for me as well it is giving for 00:00:00. On further investigation, I came across this [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

> The server interprets date as a value in the current time zone and
>   converts it to an internal value in UTC. Clients can set their time
>   zone as described in Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”.

On further searching, it became apparent that there is a variable [system_time_zone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), that is set when server starts using server machine's timezone. [See here also](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone)

For each client connecting, they can set their own timezone as

```
mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;
```

So finally, you need to check your [system_time_zone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), set it to proper value.

I hope it will work well then....

Comment: hi. thanks for the response. I think yes, this is related to the timezone of our system. Mine is in India UTC+5:30. And also 24:00 - 5:30 is 18:30 which is an interesting revelation I just came up with. Can you check with the time zone in which you checked the above queries and add to the response? Thanks

Comment: Is your MySQL server running locally in India, or somewhere else?

Comment: yeah locally in india. ubuntu.

Comment: will you provide the output value you are getting for  "2007-11-30 10:30:19", "2007-11-30 00:00:00" and "2007-11-30"

Comment: dunno how but this seems to be working fine now. [one](http://imgur.com/ANgVA) [two](http://imgur.com/xCb5o) [three](http://imgur.com/Uljdg) closing the question

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make sure, that the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function returns the correct timestamp irrespective of anything interfering with the timezone etc

```
>> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(t.DATE,' 00:00:00')) FROM db.table_name t
```

That is, to append the 00:00:00 manually in the query string.