# How to deal with PHP + MySQL timezones and MySQL GROUP BY [date] queries?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, datetime, timezone

I'm working with Drupal 7, PHP, and MySQL, and trying to get my head around timezone issues when querying from the MySQL database.

Drupal handles dates pretty well out of the gate: all dates are stored as UTC timestamp int's in the db, and timezone conversion happens on a per-user basis via a timezone setting in each user profile, using PHP 5's built-in timezone capabilities (so each time a PHP script is run the script's timezone is set to the current user's timezone).

So this is all fine and dandy and fairly painless as long as we stick to PHP.

Things start to get tricky when we bring in MySQL, **since there doesn't appear to be a way to perfectly synchronize the current PHP script timezone with a given MySQL query**. It seems like best practice dictates handling ALL timezone conversion in PHP: only ever querying the database for the raw timestamps, and then converting in PHP as necessary.

This seems reasonable in most cases (even if a bit slower at times), **but what am I supposed to do with MySQL GROUP BY [date] queries**? For instance, I'm building a module to handle analytics, and frequently want to do things like:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.created)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.created))
```

So we run into the timezone issue...

Possible solutions that have come to mind:

1. Hard-code a timezone: Use date_default_timezone_set() within my module to insure that the PHP timezone is always set to the system timezone (so MySQL timezone = PHP timezone). In other words, the analytics timezone will be hard-coded, rather than respecting the timezone of the user viewing the analytics. This really isn't ideal, since we want users in multiple timezones to be able to access the analytics using their timezones. Also, date_default_timezone_set() seems to mess Drupal up, as it sets the timezone for the entire script, instead of just within a particular function...
2. Forget about using GROUP BY in the queries: just fetch all the raw data from the db (be there tens or hundreds of thousands of rows), then group the results by date in php using for loops... this solution seems like it would be significantly more resource intensive, slower, and somewhat ridiculous.

So I guess what I'm asking is, have I missed something? Is there a best practice here that I'm not aware of?

Thanks a ton for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an approach such as this

```
SET time_zone = '+02:00';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

And have

```
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(u.created, '%Y-%m');
```

Since `FROM_UNIXTIME` bases it's time on `time_zone`, this should give desired result.

To undo the `time_zone` change afterwards, consider saving [`SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), CONVERT_TZ(now(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00'));`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql#answer-3984412) first and then set it to saved value afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Robin. The issue with MySQL SET time_zone is that the scope is for the entire client connection, rather than for a particular query, so as far as I understand, the new timezone would affect every Drupal db query. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: [Get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql) and save the default `time_zone` and run a query afterwards which resets it to previous value.

Comment: That solution seems extremely hack-y to me. Correct me if I'm wrong, but with the potential for thousands of page views per minute, it seems like there would be no way to guarantee that additional queries were not executed between the time that the timezone was changed and reset. Of course, I'm thankful for the suggestion in any case... not like I've come up with a better idea...

Comment: It'd only affect the current execution for all I know. And that executes 1 query at a time. Therefor I see no problem here. `Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time zone setting, given by the session time_zone variable.`

Comment: Thank you Robin for your help. I still feel wary about this, though... I guess I'm not certain about when a db "connection" begins and ends, as far as Drupal is concerned... do you have any knowledge in this regard, can you point to any documentation?