# How to handle user's data stored in the database if user's timezone changes using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cron, timezone

If a user sets a reminder notification time exactly at `8 AM`, he should get the notification exactly at `8 AM` even after he moved to a different `timezone`.

I mean if he moved to any other country with different timezone even after that he should get the notification exactly at `8 AM` on the morning of that country.

To send notifications, I'm using `CRON` which is running in `UTC timezon`e.

Consider this example, user's reminder time is 8 AM in `IST (+5:30)`, I'm storing `2:30` in UTC into the database. But what if he moved to `EDT (-4:00)` timezone area? But also I have a huge amount of data of the user.

Please suggest the solution considering that I have to perform that operation using PHP and the database is `MySQL`.

Comment: The time in the database should be saved in UTC. Then you can have extra column with the offset. Then you can choose if you want to fetch the time in UTC or by the users timezone (the offset). That way, you only need to update the offset for the user in the database. Some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017799/how-to-convert-utc-date-to-local-time-zone-in-mysql-select-query

Comment: I already have user's timezone. I'm also updating the timezone if he moved to a different timezone.

Comment: If all the dates are stored as UTC, then check the link I posted to.

Comment: You didn't got what is the problem here. Consider this example, user's reminder time is 8 AM in IST (+5:30), I'm storing 2:30 in UTC into the database. If he moved to EDT (-4:00) timezone area and I'm going to convert the stored time (2:30) to user's new timezone (-4:00), I'll get 10:30 PM of the previous day. Which is not correct. It should be 8 AM, not 10:30 PM on the previous day. And don't forget I'm using CRON Jobs to send notifications.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant: If the user wants to get a notification at 8 am (no matter the timezone), store 8 am UTC in the database. Then, when you do your query, you compare the stored notification date (converted to the users timezone) with the current local time (in the users timezone). That way, it will always notify you at 8 am in the users local timezone.

Comment: What is CRON ? (I've heard of cron - but that is a package - only specific components of which can be "run")

Comment: Follow these links https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron and http://coderssecret.com/how-to-write-cron-jobs-on-aws-ec2-instance/

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm using CRON to send notifications and the server is in UTC. I can't store the time directly. Please tell me if you got this or want me to explain.

Comment: _"with the current local time (in the users timezone)"_ = The systems current time (as you stated was UTC), converted to the users timezone. It doesn't matter where you run the script.

Comment: This works fine if a user stays in a single timezone but what if he changed the timezone?

Comment: The user obviously needs to update his/hers timezone in your database somehow. It's pretty impossible for you for your script to magically know what timezone the user is in otherwise. If the user updates the timezone, then _that_ timezone will be used in your query instead. It might help us to know more about what this is. App? Web site? Send notifications through mail? How does the user define the timezone to begin with?

Comment: You still didn't get the situation here. I have user's timezone (timezone is getting updated when the app detects the changes in the timezone). If he moved to a different timezone, I'm updating the existing timezone with this new one but the problem is with the data of the user which is already there in the database. Check above example. It's an app by the way and CRON is sending push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform all my notifying operations on the server via `CRON`. Lets imagine a simple example:

1) You live in a **Country A** which has a `GMT+3` timezone. It is now `14:00 GMT+3`. You have a meeting in **Country B** which is under `GMT+1`.

2) Your meeting in this country is at `16:00 GMT+1 or 18:00 GMT+3`. So 4 more hours until the meeting.

3) You set up an appointment in your application for a meeting in `18:00 GMT+3`. All appointments in your server are saved as `GMT+0`, thus this appointment is saved as `15:00 GMT+0`.

4) Let us imagine you teleport to the country of the meeting and the time is now `12:00 GMT+1`. After 4 hours have passed (`16:00 GMT+1, 18:00 GMT+3, 15:00 GMT+0`), you will still be notified by the server, regardless of your change in timezone. Since the server will have your appointment saved as GMT+0 and will be checking with a `CRON` job every, lets say 5 minutes`, if someone's appointment is due.

On the other hand, if you wanna perform the check on the client, you should always transform the client's datetime to whatever format is saved on the server and check with the server.

Comment: The CRON is checking the current GMT time and matches with users reminder time using MySQL query. And also this notification contains some information of the user by fetching data from MySQL relational database. The problem is with existing users data. It is still the same with respect to country A and we have lots of users data. If I perform MySQL join operations or some other conditions which require the time of the user then we'll always get the wrong result.