# Get count of new customers along with count of unique customers per month

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following columns:

```
Amount;
Discount;
Timestamp (UTC) with two years 2016/2017;
Order_ID;
Customer_ID
```

Now I want to get a list of unique customers along with new customers (who have never transacted before) per month between Jan-2016 and Feb-2017 but as per my local time zone i.e. IST and not UTC

I have written the below code to get unique customers per month but not able to understand how to incorporate count(new customers) and change time zone simultaneously

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS total, 
       SUM(discount) AS tdisc, 
       YEAR(timestamp) AS yyyy, 
       MONTH(timestamp) AS mm, 
       COUNT(order_id), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(customer_id)) AS distcid 
FROM table t 
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), 
         MONTH(timestamp) 
HAVING YEAR(timestamp) >= 2016 AND 
       YEAR(timestamp) < 2017 
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Comment: For converting the time zone see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15018103/3986005

Comment: To know if a customer is new, you need to know if an order is the first order of a customer. For this is would be useful if `Order_ID` contains an integer that auto increases with time. In other words: Orders are numbered chronologically. Is that the case here?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you for directing me to the timezone link. And no orders are not numbered chronologically in my case

Comment: Are you saying the timestamp does not represent a chronological order?