# mysql server gives UTC time, is there any way to set query to give CST time without specifying convert timezone?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Query,

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1581428320), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') as time` gives different time,

```
Local:  02/11/2020 07:38:40  
Server: 02/11/2020 13:38:40
```

I am on aws ec2 instance, there is way to set timezone but it needs reboot instance, unfortunately i cant able to reboot. is there anyother way to get CST time without changing query?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017799/how-to-convert-utc-date-to-local-time-zone-in-mysql-select-query

Comment: @jarmod, i am trying without updating query. because there is lot of query