# How can I change timezone in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone

I have this query, how can in change the timezone to an indian timezone in this query

```sql
SELECT 'ENTRIES' as Module, concat(SUM(t.TotalEntry)) AS VAL 
FROM fantasy.Game t 
WHERE t.DateModified BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:01') 
                         AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 10:00:00')
```

Comment: i'm using MySQL

Comment: The syntax claims that you use MySQL. So: #1. Use TIMESTAMP() function, not CONCAT; #2. For timezone changing use CONVERT_TZ() function; #3. In `concat(SUM(t.TotalEntry))` the CONCAT usage is excess - remove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert UTC Date To Local time Zone in MySql Select Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017799/how-to-convert-utc-date-to-local-time-zone-in-mysql-select-query)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL the CONVERT_TZ() returns a resulting value after converting a datetime value from a time zone specified as the second argument to the time zone specified as the third argument. This function returns NULL when the arguments are invalid.

**Syntax:**

```
CONVERT_TZ(dt, from_tz, to_tz)
```

from_tz and to_tz are timezone variables and could be numeric or timezone name.
Look at this link for more datail:

[Official MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)