# How to convert a date time column in IST time format

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to convert a date time field which is in UTC format to IST time format.

This is the query which I have.

> select file_name,Process_start_time,Process_end_time from Process_logs

where process_Start_time and process_end_time are in UTC format which I want in IST format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert UTC Date To Local time Zone in MySql Select Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017799/how-to-convert-utc-date-to-local-time-zone-in-mysql-select-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `convert_tz`

```
 convert_tz(date,from_time_zone,to_time_zone)
```

obviously `IST` is 5.30 hours ahead of `UTC`

```
select file_name,
       convert_tz(Process_start_time,'+00:00','+05:30'),
       convert_tz(Process_end_time,'+00:00','+05:30') from Process_logs
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a UTC to IST in MySQL, you can use the `CONVERT_TZ` function.

```
SELECT
    file_name,
    CONVERT_TZ(Process_start_time, 'UTC', 'Asia/Kolkata') AS IST_Process_start_time,
    CONVERT_TZ(Process_end_time, 'UTC', 'Asia/Kolkata') AS IST_Process_end_time
FROM Process_logs;
```