# Convert unix time to UTC datetime

Tags: mysql, time, utc, epoch

I'm trying to insert a timestamp into the database, I need the timestamp to be in UTC time, not the server's time zone.

```
INSERT INTO my_table SET time = FROM_UNIXTIME(:epochTime)
```

But the newly inserted datetime value is not in UTC time, how can I do this?

Perhaps I should also use [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz), but I don't know the timezone from which I convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup I would look at CONVERT_TZ:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

To grab the timezone from mysql:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

Edit:  The query below returns the timezone of the current session.

```
select timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00'));
```

URL for some info: [How do I get the current time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql)

If the server has a different timezone, tell us your Operating system or location.

Comment: Thanks - `CONVERT_TZ(from_unixtime(1395928430), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')`

Comment: Yeah that's actually right, SYSTEM is a valid timezone and can be converted using now() etc.  I should have highlighted that, glad it's working.

Comment: Also I found that I can do `SET @@session.time_zone := '+00:00'; SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1395928430)` which would be handy if inserting multiple columns.