# How to know my timezone in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to know which is my timezone (`GMT`, or `GMT+1` or ...).
There's any function in MySQL to know it?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: By your timezone do you mean the timezone of the MySQL server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
```