# Is there any timezone attached with datetime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timezone

Is there any timezone attached (like metadata) with every datetime field values in MySQL? Or every dates are independent of timezone?

Comment: No, there is no time zone stored in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Is there any timezone attached (like metadata) with every datetime field values in MySQL?
```

No, there is no timezone stored in DB with every date (like metadata). MySQL, by default, takes the timezone of the server for all stored dates.

To find out what it is try to run this in the shell

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

Now as you can see there are always these 2 timezones for the serve

1. Global(for all mysql connections)
2. Session - local to the connection

Go through this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql) to read more about this.
Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-timezone-of-mysql) to read how to change/set it