# Matching a PHP time() output to precisely what MySQL's now() would be

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am working in a codebase where I have an unfortunate circumstance.

A row is being inserted into the MySQL database where a `time` column is being set as `null`, but the column is `nn` and defaults to `NOW()`.

However, I need that value. Without using a select query to pull that time, is there any way I can *ensure* that a PHP function's output is the exact same value?

Does `time() === now()` always? Can timezone settings screw it up? What are the implications of doing the code like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things

Mysql now() and PHP time() are not same. PHP `time()` will be an unixtime stamp representation in digits, where as mysql `now()` will be in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-04-14 13:15:10 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And in php `time()` will return something as `1428997570`

In mysql you can use the function `unix_timestamp()`

```
mysql> select unix_timestamp() ;
+------------------+
| unix_timestamp() |
+------------------+
|       1428997518 |
+------------------+
```

The most important part is if the apache timezone and mysql timezone does not match then you are likely to get different values using `time()` and `unix_timestamp()` and hence the comparison fails

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was fearing. Turns out MySQL has stored 10 million records in its local timezone. I did some [more reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql) and it turns out to even get MySQL's timezone you also need to run a query, which defeats what I'm going for. So, to Google explorers, the answer appears to be: **Redo your code so that this isn't a problem.**

Comment: If your mysql timezone is different than that of your apache then you still have a function to do the conversion while matching https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Answer (score 1):

time() Function in PHP return the time in secounds since 1970, as to:
[time in php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

The function in MySQL equal to this is: UNIX_TIMESTAMP as to: [unix_timestamp from MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Thefore time()==unix_timestamp()

Hope thats help! :)