# Fixing db query with time offset

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a query where I check data against the current date and current time:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
AND DATE(event_date ) = '".$cur_date."'
AND event_time > '" . $cur_time . "'
```

where

```
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d');
$cur_time = date('H:i');
```

However, we just added additional column to the db table that contains UTC time offset, expressed in minutes, currently: -300

I need to adjust the query to reflect the adjustment. Not really sure how to do it in mySQL. In PHP I just do something like this:

```
date('g:i A', strtotime($event_date) + ($offset_time * 60));
```

My db is located on a different server. The only way to know it's relative time to my user location is via UTC time offset.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2934271/175063

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `CURDATE(),CURTIME()`

```
SELECT FROM table 
WHERE 
AND DATE(event_date) = CURDATE()
AND event_time > CURTIME()
```

Comment: My db is located on a different server. The only way to know it's relative time to my user location is via UTC time offset.

Comment: use **timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00'))**

Comment: SELECT FROM table 
WHERE 
AND DATE(event_date) = CURDATE()
AND event_time > timediff(NOW(),convert_tz(NOW(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00'))

Comment: try this query @santa

Comment: If the db server time is 5 hours ahead of the user's local time, CURDATE() will be different starting after 5pm...

Comment: @Rahautos: Can you merge the code in comments into the actual answer?

Answer (score 0):

First you set time zone of mysql :-

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5:00';//your time_zone
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';//your time_zone name
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';
```