# IF and AND in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Concert:
id | name | date
1  | aaa  | 2016-02-14
2  | bbb  | 2016-02-15

Times:
id | concert_id | time
1  | 1          | 10:00:00
2  | 1          | 16:00:00
3  | 1          | 21:00:00
4  | 2          | 10:00:00
5  | 2          | 15:00:00
6  | 2          | 21:00:00
```

I would like get concerts by day. For example for "2016-02-14":

```
SELECT * FROM Concert as c LEFT JOIN Times as t ON c.id = t.concert_id WHERE c.date = '2016-02-14' AND t.time > CURTIME()
```

This working ok, return only Times with ID 3, but for:

```
SELECT * FROM Concert as c LEFT JOIN Times as t ON c.id = t.concert_id WHERE c.date = '2016-02-15' AND t.time > CURTIME()
```

also returns last ID (6). Should be all times (4, 5, 6), because this is next day.

How can I compare CURTIME with CURDATE for my example? IF expression? But how?

Comment: You will get different results depending on when you execute each query since the CURTIME() function returns the current time of the server.

Comment: What would you store times in one table and dates in another?

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want `NOW()`.  But that doesn't work because the time and dates are in different columns.  The basic query for upcoming concerts is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Concert c JOIN
     Times t
     ON c.id = t.concert_id
WHERE (c.date = '2016-02-14' AND t.time > CURTIME() ) OR
      (c.date > '2016-02-14');
```

Actually, you can replace `'2016-02-14'` with `CURDATE()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURDATE for the actual date

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Concert as c 
  LEFT JOIN Times as t ON c.id = t.concert_id 
  WHERE c.date = CURDATE() AND t.time > CURTIME();
```

or convert the date you prefer

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Concert as c 
  LEFT JOIN Times as t ON c.id = t.concert_id 
  WHERE c.date =str_to_date('2016-02-14', '%Y/%m/%d') 
  AND t.time > CURTIME();
  str_to_date('2016-02-14', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a timezone issue. Please refer to the link below to check your timezone on mysql:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql
```

Also, your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Concert as c LEFT JOIN Times as t ON c.id = t.concert_id WHERE c.date = '2016-02-15' AND t.time > CURTIME()
```

If you're calling this from PHP you can replace `CURTIME()` with whatever current date is given in PHP (and you can echo the query to debug).

As it is, really depends on what time is `CURTIME()`, because if your timezone is different in MySQL, you may think you are running a query at 20:00, when actually it could be 23:00...