# how to get mySQL server time zone in +/- hours

Tags: mysql, timezone

When i SELECT @@system_time_zone it gives me output as named time zone instead of hours:

@@system_time_zone
Arab Standard Time

I know that Arab Standard Time is +03:00 but i want output as +03:00 instead of named timezone.

May I ask for help from experts?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think you should not relying on the server time, but rather storing timezone information in your `datetime` objects.  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that provides you with the expected result:

```
-- set some time zone
set @@session.time_zone='Asia/Kolkata';  
select concat( concat(if(timestampdiff(hour, utc_timestamp,current_timestamp)>0,'+',''),
timestampdiff(hour, utc_timestamp, current_timestamp)),
':',
MOD(timestampdiff(minute, utc_timestamp, current_timestamp), 60)) as zone_diff from dual;


+-----------+
| zone_diff |
+-----------+
| +5:30     |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the default time Zone in PhP. Atfer that you can create an new date object which gives you the time in the TimeZone you set.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
```

Look at this for more information: http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-get.php