# how to get my local time from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Column `date` is `timestamp` - default - `current_timestamp`

example value: `2017-04-07 09:45:53`

```
$stmt = $db->query("select * from cinema order by date desc");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $date = strtotime($row['date']);
        $datea = date("d-m-y", $date);
        $time = date("H:i", $date);
```

I'm getting -2 hours difference comparing to my timezone - `09:45` instead of `11:45` - so I tried:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT *, CONVERT_TZ(date, '+00:00', '+01:00') FROM cinema order by date desc"); - without success
```

I also tried to change column type from `timestamp (current_timestamp)` to `datetime (current_timestamp)`.

And still getting -2 hours difference.

Any help?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT *, CONVERT_TZ(date, @@session.time_zone, '+02:00') AS mydate FROM cinema order by mydate desc");
```

Here are some reading that might be helpful when working with date and time:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075291/1363190