# finding the server timezone using SQL

Tags: oracle

I need to find the server timezone, in this form :

`UTC: (SIGN)(HOURS):(MINUTES)`

My code is :

```
SELECT 'UTC' || EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOURS FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) || ':' || 
EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) || '0' AS tz_offest;
```

But I am still missing the sign (+) or (-) , how can I put the sign?

Comment: is this `MySQL` ?

Comment: I've guessed you may be asking about Oracle (you are clearly **not using MySQL**). If it isn't the case, please add the correct tag yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
    IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP) >= '00:00:00', '+', '-'),
    SUBSTR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@SESSION .time_zone, '+00:00')), 1, 5)
) AS timezone;
```

Reference answer from [How do I get the current time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3984412/5559741)