# Get result from query in timezone user rather than timezone DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timezone

I have a Mysql DB on time zone UTC and PHP server in Timezone Europe, Bucharest (GMT+03:00).

When query like giving me result in month=8 and year=2018, because different Timezone there's some result in month 7. The result in month 8 in DB Timezone start from 31-07-2018 21:00 to 31-08-2018 21:00 not (start from 01-08-2018 00:00 to 31-08-2018 23:59) is a real result for my client in his time zone.

So is there a way to set Timezone on query and get exactly result meet Timezone of my client?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql)

Comment: You may also want to read [this article](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/convert-the-mysql-time-zone).

Comment: is user location or timezone stored in your database ?

Comment: @DrJManish no it is in whole system currently I don't need user timezone
only my system in timezone and db in different timezone