# How to use Angular date pipe to convert a date coming from server formatted as local time but actually in UTC?

Tags: mysql, angular, datetime, angular8

I am getting data back from server like `2020-02-17 15:36:47` (with no time zone descriptor).  This is a date that is generated BY the server and is actually in UTC time (the server's "local" time).  However, it is stored as DateTime in MySQL without time zone information.

When I get this back from the server, I need to convert it to local time, but when I try to apply date pipe like `dateVariable | date: 'short' : 'UTC'` it actually *adds* time rather than takes it away (my local time is EST) - so I get `2/17/20, 8:36 PM` where it should actually be `2/17/20, 10:36 AM`.

I guess ths issue is that the client assumes the time coming from the server is already local time, and my pipe is converting it to UTC.  In fact, I want to do the opposite - the server time is stored as UTC (even though it is not indicated as such in MySQL DateTime column), and I want to convert to EST (local) using the date pipe.  I've searched about and not sure how to handle this outside of modifying what the server returns.

Comment: take the date and time  and add your timezone in js. the mysql server timezone you can get so https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934271/5193536

Comment: I don't have an absolute tested suggestion for you, but I don't think datePipe by itself will do what you want. I would suggest looking at moment-timezone. I haven't tried it, but I think something like moment.tz(dateVariable, "UTC") should get you close...  [Play around, it took me a while to find the combinations that worked for my needs.]