# MYSQL and PHP giving different times if time is converted from UTC -> Local or vice versa

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

Why are these two things showing different times?

```
select CONVERT_TZ('2023-05-03 00:00:00', '-06:00', @@global.time_zone);
Outputs:

2023-05-03 06:00:00


$date = new \DateTime('2023-05-03 00:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
Outputs:

2023-05-03 05:00:00
```

-06:00 is America/Chicago. So why there is a difference of 1 hour? Can any one guide me to the correct way please?

Comment: Using [GMT, like this might be of some use to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934271/1389394)

Comment: Assuming that `@@global.time_zone` equal `UTC` (please verify just in case), Chicago current time appears to be -0500 ([source](https://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_US-IL.aspx?city=Chicago)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-06:00 is America/Chicago" - no, that depends on time of year.  When you pass -06:00 you mean exactly that offset, with no daylight saving rules.  Pass "America/Chicago" instead.  (If it then returns null, you need to load the MySQL timezone tables - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html )

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did the same thing, instead of passing "-06:00", I passed America/Chicago and that helped me fix my problem.