# mySQL DATE functions in ExpressJS evaluates to a day earlier than input

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I'm connecting to mySQL using express, and anytime I try to use any DATE functions it always evaluates to one day earlier than the provided date and always at 5pm

For example:

```
connection.query('SELECT DATE("2001-02-15")', (err, rows, fields) => console.log(rows))
```

This gives the output:

```
[ RowDataPacket { 'DATE("2001-02-15")': 2001-02-14T17:00:00.000Z } ]
```

Another example when I ran this on July 3:

```
connection.query('SELECT CURDATE()', (err, rows, fields) => console.log(rows))

[ RowDataPacket { 'CURDATE()': 2023-07-02T17:00:00.000Z } ]
```

Using the mySQL shell gives me the correct date though:

```
+------------+
| CURDATE()  |
+------------+
| 2023-07-03 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.0008 sec)
```

My mySQL server is using my system's time zone, which is set to UTC +7, and the system_time_zone variable in mySQL workbench says SE Asia Standard Time. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Edit: worth noting that using NOW() gives a time 7hours earlier than my time, which suggests ExpressJS is for some reason in UTC+0 (my time currently is 7:32)

```
connection.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, rows, fields) => console.log(rows))
[ RowDataPacket { 'NOW()': 2023-07-03T12:31:13.000Z } ]
```

query for time zone

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; 
+--------------------+---------------------+ 
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone | 
+--------------------+---------------------+ 
| SYSTEM | SYSTEM | 
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

i think they both use system time zone, which is UTC+7 according to my laptop's time zone settings

Comment: which timezone has your server? and your connection ?

Comment: please add new information to the query and not as comment

Comment: also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql  to get the necessary exact information

Answer (score 1):

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '****',
  user: '****',
  password: '****',
  database: '****',
  timezone: 'utc'
})
```

adding the timezone when initializing the connection fixed the issues for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).